# How do I get the textbox name after it's focused or clicked in vba

Tags: excel, vba

How can I get the name of the current textbox (activex control)that is focused or clicked on in VBA? Note this textbox is on a worksheet and not a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```vb
Dim ActiveShape As Object

Private Sub TextBox1_GotFocus()
    Set ActiveShape = Me.TextBox1
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_GotFocus()
    Set ActiveShape = Me.TextBox2
End Sub

Sub Test()
    MsgBox "You are currently on, or have recently clicked on " & ActiveShape.Name
End Sub
```

I put `ActiveShape` as a [Module-Level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/glossary/vbe-glossary#module-level) variable, this will save it between executions. Then for each of your textboxes, put a script in their `_GotFocus` event. This script will save the most recently interacted textbox onto the `ActiveShape` variable.

If you want to, you can put a script into each textboxes `_LostFocus` event to set `ActiveShape` to `Nothing`. This will ensure `ActiveShape` is only the currently active shape and not the most recently active shape, if you care about that distinction.